# What Requirements Do I Need to Comply with in Order to Fly a Custom Drone Commercially in Texas

Tags: regulations, license

I'm currently in the process of selecting parts for use in both a quad and VTOL flying wing drones. Both drones are going to weigh over 250 grams but I don't know what the total weight will be yet although they will both be under the 50 pound or so limit the FAA has in place. The quad will be used for photography while the VTOL will be used for cargo carrying packages up to 40lbs and the VTOLs total weight with cargo will not exceed the 50lb limit. I know I'm probably going to need a license but IDK which one or if I'm going to need more than one. Also, I just want to fly a freaking drone without giving all of my personal info away to the government. Is there any way I can obtain a FAA license without having to provide a photo ID? I know a little bit about the registration process but tbh, my info is several years old and it's very confusing. I live in Texas if that has any relevance to the regulations. If there's anything else I should be aware of regarding registration in general or requirements for the drone itself then please feel free to share. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you :D

Answer (score 1):

In general Drone is considered as UAS (Unmanned Aircraft System)
The FAA has basic information on their website https://www.faa.gov/uas/
In order to fly the drone, the drone need to be registered it cost US $ 5 for 3 years.
and for personnel flying the drone need to have adequate knowledge on regulations, procedures including map and charts, notam, etc if you intent to operate commercially then Part 107 of US FAA regulations applies.
For carrying goods especially cargo,  as far as airmen certification personnel detail is required, although picture is not displayed in the license however for security reason personal details including address is required.  see the license information [here](https://www.aviationpros.com/airports/article/12414488/how-do-i-get-a-drone-license)  and [official FAA page](https://iacra.faa.gov/IACRA/HelpAndInfo.aspx?id=5) for license registration, the FAA is cover for all United states, including Texas.
I hope this help